# How do you use glVerttexAttribPointer in conjunction with glBufferData?

Tags: ipad, opengl-es-2.0, vertex-buffer

In the stock "rotating cube" OpenGL example for iOS 5, they have this code:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(gCubeVertexData), gCubeVertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, BUFFER_OFFSET(12));
```

The messed up part there is the last argument to `glVertexAttribPointer`. [The docs](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml) say the last argument is a pointer to an array.

But in this program they are using straight numbers.  Indeed, `BUFFER_OFFSET` is defined as

```
#define BUFFER_OFFSET(i) ((char *)NULL + (i))
```

So are they relying on their `gCubeVertexData` array starting at memory address 0?

So, I don't understand 2 things:

1. **Why doesn't the example work** (no cubes are drawn) **when I "correct" the 3rd line of code to**

   ```
   glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, gCubeVertexData );
   ```
2. What is the correct way to invoke glVertexAttribPointer?

I thought you were supposed to pass a memory pointer for the last index as the documentation says.  Indeed, here [another sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData.html) uses glVertexAttribPointer:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_POSITION, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertexStruct), &vertices[0].position);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_POSITION);
glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_COLOR, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_TRUE, sizeof(vertexStruct), &vertices[0].color);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_COLOR);
```

So you see in the latter example they have passed *memory addresses* for *pointer* (last arg), not straight numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

glVertexAttribPointer can be used in two ways:

1) With client side vertex arrays. In this case, the final argument is a pointer to an array, you're correct about this.

2) In addition to being used as a pointer, if you read further down in that documentation page you linked, it says this:

> If a non-zero named buffer object is bound to the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER target (see glBindBuffer) while a generic vertex attribute array is specified, pointer is treated as a byte offset into the buffer object's data store.

This is for when you're using the glVertexAttribPointer to point at a VBO, a buffer that you've previously uploaded to opengl (glBindBuffer/glBufferData).

To clarify:

If you don't have an active buffer bound with glBindBuffer, glVertexAttribArray takes a pointer. If you do have a buffer bound, then glVertexAttribArray takes an offset into the bound buffer. This will be the value `0` if you want to start drawing from the start of the buffer.